# filter selected range by column value in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am copying successfully a range from one excel to another using powershell, like this:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false 
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($pathSource) 
$WorkbookDestination = $excel.Workbooks.open($pathDestination) 
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("Page 1") 
$Worksheet.activate()  
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($columnName).EntireColumn


$range.Copy() | out-null 
$WorksheetDestination = $WorkbookDestination.Worksheets.item("Destination") 
$Range = $WorksheetDestination.Range("A1") 
$WorksheetDestination.Paste($range)  
$WorkbookDestination.Save()  
$Excel.Quit() 
Remove-Variable -Name excel
```

I want to filter information (i.e column 18 equals "some value") from selected range, prior copying to another excel.

PowerShell v2.

Comment: I can't find a good example, but you can SQL query Excel ranges http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2012/07/reading-updating-and-inserting-data.html

Comment: Thanks Slai. I reallly like how it sounds and looks. I'm Gonna try it and publish it in here if it works, as I think it will.